# How to calculate distance between a fixture and a point in Box2D/Farseer?

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, distance, farseer

Basically, I have a fixture, and a point. I want to know the distance between them (not between their centers).

I know there exists the Distance API, but it only works with 2 fixtures :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more math knowledge that you should knew. Distance between two objects is a length of vector between their coordinates. Farseer uses Xna type Vector2 or Vector3. Just subtract two needed vectors to get the needed one and get *Length* through the method on the corresponding vector type. Fixture's coordinates are under its *Body.Position*.

For distance to specific point using shape of your fixture just create fake pointShape from it (use for your needs circle with minimum radius) and then use Distance class.

```
float getDistance(Vector2 point, Fixture fixture)
{
    var proxyA = new DistanceProxy();
    proxyA.Set(fixture.Shape, 0);

    var proxyB = new DistanceProxy();
    // prepare point shape
    var pointShape = new CircleShape(0.0001, 1);
    proxyB.Set(pointShape, 0);

    Transform transformA;
    fixture.Body.GetTransform(out transformA);

    Transform transformB = new Transform();
    transformB.Set(point, 0);

    DistanceOutput distance;
    SimplexCache cache;

    FarseerPhysics.Collision.Distance.ComputeDistance(out distance, out cache,
                new FarseerPhysics.Collision.DistanceInput(){
                    UseRadii=true,
                    ProxyA=proxyA,
                    ProxyB=proxyB,
                    TransformA=transformA,
                    TransformB=transformB
                });
}
```

Comment: No, you are wrong. This is distance between centers. I want the distance to the actual shape.

Comment: Your question doesn't contains these specifics, because as far as I know distance between centers is a fairly common solution. Just edited my answer for actual fixture shape.

Comment: I actually ended up doing a similar thing, however you do not have to create a `Fixture` for that - just a `Shape` (check my edit).